# Need help starting lighttpd

Tags: php, lighttpd

Today I installed lighttpd on my CentOS 5.6 machine attempting to replace httpd.

The things I did:

`yum install lighttpd`

`nano /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf` *I set the document root to my files*

`service lighttpd start` *-- [root@forums ~]# Starting lighttpd: 2011-05-20 18:52:34: (network.c.203) socket failed: Address family not supported by protocol*

> Starting lighttpd: 2011-05-20
>   18:52:34: (network.c.203) socket
>   failed: Address family not supported
>   by protocol

How can I fix this? I really want to try out lighttpd for my forum but I just can't get it to start. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting "server.use-ipv6" to disabled and start lighttpd.

It could be trying to load ipv6 settings and the server has ipv6 disabled.